How to set \noalign globally
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{array}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{array}{%
 \hskip-\arraycolsep%
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{array}{%
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
 \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}%
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{array}{%
\hskip-\arraycolsep%
} 
\AtEndEnvironment{array}{%
\\\noalign{\vspace{-1pt}}%
}
\begin{document} 
$
f(x)=\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
    \noalign{\vspace{-1.5ex}}-x-1, &x \leq 0, \\ 
    \ln (x+1),& x>0.
\end{array}
\right.
$
\end{document}


how to put \noalign{\vspace{-1.5ex}} in the preamble？

if you are adding this negative vertical space to adjust the size of the { there are much more direct ways to achieve that, adding 1.5ex negative space to every array is sure to cause text to overprint in some documents

To long for the comment ...
Sorry, at least to me, it is not clear what you after.
From showed math expression thought that I would rather use ˙casesenvironment defined in theamsmathpackage and not bother with vertical space abovearray`. For example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 
\lipsum[66]
\[
f(x)=\begin{cases}
    -x-1,       &   x \leq 0, \\[1ex] 
    \ln (x+1),  &   x>0.
    \end{cases}
\]
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}


BTW, such expression I wouldn't use in line math. It (to much) disturb spaces between lines in text.
